# Is it legal to work in Western Australia without permanent residency?

Tags: legal, australia

I'm a student who moved to Western Australia for the next two years. I'm a minor, and I moved with the rest of my family because of my father's job, but, the visa we are here on means we are not permanent residents. Is it legal for me to get a job in Western Australia despite not being a permanent resident?

Comment: We have a site called [expatriates.se] that specifically deals with questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can check your work entitlements (among other things) online using the [Department of Home Affairs VEVO system](https://online.immi.gov.au/evo/firstParty?actionType=query).

You will need your passport and visa details (transaction reference number, grant number, etc.). Here's an example of what it might say:

> Work entitlements: The Visa Holder has unlimited Work Entitlements
>
> Workplace rights: All employees in Australia are protected by workplace laws, including visa holders, for further information see:
> https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/work-rights-and-exploitation

You will also need to check [WA's rules](https://www.commerce.wa.gov.au/labour-relations/when-children-can-work-western-australia).